# Add o'clock/Uhr to a globalize.js formatted date

Tags: javascript, jquery-globalize

Pretty simple question: I want to add a switch to my globalize format skeleton, so that it adds an "o'clock" or German "Uhr" after the time. Right now, I'm using the following pattern:

yMMddHHmm

I found the o'clock string in the respective cldr files, but I don't know how to add them to the skeleton.

Here's my code:

```
Globalize.formatDate(dTermin, { skeleton: 'yMMddHHmm' });
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no skeleton that would give you "o'clock" kinda output [1]. Although, if you really want that format and are willing to provide the i18n data for all the locales you think could support it you can use globalize's `raw` option like:

```
// Not recommended anyway...
if (locale === "en") {
    formatter = globalize.dateFormatter({raw: "HH 'o''clock'"});
}
```

Though, it's usually a not recommended approach since you have to maintain this list of custom formatters yourself.

1: In order to check, I've grep'ed the whole CLDR and found no match.

Comment: That's exactly my concern! The weird thing is, that there are those strings in the CLDR files, but I have no idea, if and how I can access them.

Comment: Looks like there are only in the German files. For example ca-generic.json, Line 340 ("H": "HH 'Uhr'",), 388 and 413, as well as ca-gregorian.json, Line 345 ("h": "h 'Uhr' a",) and so on …

Comment: For the examples above, you can use `{skeleton: 'H'}` and `{skeleton: 'h'}` respectively.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work! However, as soon as I add the minutes, the "Uhr" disappears again. Looks like it's not meant to be used that way. Thank you anyways!